# Symfony2: check whether session exists or not

Tags: session, symfony

Is there a method to check whether a session exists or not?

I tried this method, but it always gives me a 'Bravo !' answer:

```
        $session = $this->getRequest()->hasPreviousSession();

        if($session)
        {
            return new Response('Bravo !');

        }
        else
        {
            return new Response('Oooops !');
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but `hasPreviousSession` works fine for me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$this->container->get('session')->isStarted()
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: Wrong. `isStarted` returns `false` unless you call `get` or `set` even if the request actually has a session.